# send commands to new bash and not close

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm making a script that needs to open a new bash instance, enter some commands and then let me continue using that bash instance. How do I do that? For now I have this:

```
bash << EOF
    do_something()
EOF
```

How do I make that new bash instance call do_something() and then let me enter other commands?

Later edit:

I'm actually using another company internal command, which I have no control over, that does something behind the scenes, and then gives me a preconfigured bash. That's why I've given that example of sending commands. Because it can be configured for any interpreter.

Comment: Why do you need to "open a new bash instance"? Could you expand on your larger goal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7193037 i think this is what you wanted.

Comment: @MarekRost I have updated my post. It is not what I wanted. Think of a random interpreter which gets called from bash. I want to send it some commands and then let me type other commands manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use a subshell and pipe it to bash. 'script' may help, too:

```
user@name:~$ (printf '%s\n' 'echo 1' 'echo 2'; cat) | bash
1
2
echo 3
3
user@name:~$ # DON'T do this: (printf '%s\n' 'echo 1' 'echo 2'; cat) | bash -i
user@name:~$ (printf '%s\n' 'echo 1' 'echo 2'; cat) | script -c 'bash -i' /dev/null
++++Skript gestartet, die Datei ist /dev/null
++++user@name:~$ 1
++++user@name:~$ 2
++++user@name:~$ echo 3
++++3
++++user@name:~$ Skript wurde beendet, die Datei ist /dev/null
user@name:~$
```

Remark: the plus signs don't appear at all, I've added them to clarify the 'script' part.

Instead of `script -c 'bash -i' /dev/null` you can use `script /dev/null` as the `script` command invokes `bash -i` by default.